# ubuntu image is not being read from usb on windows 10

Tags: partitioning, usb

I purchased a new laptop, windows 10 home, amd ryzen 7, 16GB RAM, 512 SSD.

I want to partition it with Ubuntu.

I downloaded ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/#download
I downloaded rufus https://rufus-usb.en.uptodown.com/windows
I followed the instructions https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-burn-an-iso-file-to-a-usb-drive-2619270, which is same as others

This was a success.

I changed BIOS to boot from USB first.

I restarted and chose option to trial Ubuntu
My laptop started to read from the USB, as it lit up momentarily, then stopped working completely.

I tried again, this time chose to install Ubuntu, and had the same result. My USB drive light flashed a few times, then nothing happened.

I tried again, and let it wait, thinking it was processing, but nothing happened after 10min or so.

This is odd, as my old laptop, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in this fashion and had no problems.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would gladly listen

Comment: From your 3rd link, be certain to follow step #6. If it doesn't boot that webpage [recommends you try this](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-device-2626091).

Comment: Some have issues with on flash drive, or one port on system, or one installer, but another installer works. And some just download ISO again and it works. No clear issue. But do you have UEFI on, UEFI fast boot off, secure boot off, Windows fast start up off, and drives set to AHCI? Many also need UEFI & SSD firmware updates.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Could also be a problem with cpu.  Goolged 'ubuntu 18.04 amd ryzen 7' and found this plus a few other pages.  ubuntu 18.04 amd ryzen 7.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159143/why-cant-any-linux-version-boot-ryzen-7Could also be a iso download, bad burn, or a bad usb.

Answer (score 0):

I typically us Etcher to flash my USB's, dunno why, but it seems to work 99% better than rufus, https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Ensure that you have turned off Fast startup on windows, or partitioning for dual boot will be non existent.

Turn off Secure boot in your Bios uefi, if you have TPM and any other fancy gadgets disable those to be safe.

boot your usb and do your thing

then make sure you turn the stuff back on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions. An update:

I downloaded 18.04 and burned with etcher to no avail, as well as with rufus,  also to no avail.

I had an old 14.04 stick that loaded, but there were issues, so could not update it from that route (could not bring up terminal).

Foolishly, maybe, I burned the 18.04.3 image over the 14.04, as I knew the 14.04 USB was functioning. Unfortunately, the same issue occurred.

I read through the 14.04 files and found an application file that is not present in the 18.04 I downloaded. Is this a cause for concern? Is there a different download source for 18.04?